# How to hack the HTML response from Apache HTTPD?

Tags: apache

I need to include some HTML fragments (into the HEAD element) for each page that is handle by HTTPD. Why? I need to hack some natives javascript functions for security policy needs.

Thank you.

Comment: You could try Firebug with Firefox. But, why do you need it? What have you tried?

Comment: I add additional information on the question.

Comment: I believe Apache provides an interface for writing third party request filters. Explore that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use mod_include http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_include.html if you can edit your existing HTML files.   If you don't want to do that, you will need to create a custom filter to post process the HTML.  You can add the custom filter with mod_filter https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/filter.html